# Why do `view` methods revert without a reason when deployed to test networks, yet work fine on localhost?

Tags: ropsten, testnets, rinkeby

I have been developing with Hardhat without problem. When I deploy my smart contracts to a test network (Ropsten or Rinkeby), none of my `view` methods work. For example:

```
function testView() public virtual view returns(bool) {
    return true;
  }
```

This function will always revert on all test networks, **even though** my transaction functions work just fine. The revert exception is:

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: call revert exception (method="testView()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.4.1)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:225:28)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:237:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:425:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:332:44)
    at step (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (/Users/zaneclaes/zdrive/zaneclaes/Programming/Furballs/node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'testView()',
  errorArgs: null,
  errorName: null,
  errorSignature: null,
  address: '0x27AbaB051007f7325ac2246187DD92b513B26d39',
  args: [ ],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x24d7806c000000000000000000000000809e2b319e4d398f9282167271ed2f69d63ef6be',
    to: '0x27AbaB051007f7325ac2246187DD92b513B26d39',
    gasLimit: BigNumber { _hex: '0x05f5e100', _isBigNumber: true },
    from: 'xxxxxx'
  }
}
```

AFAICT, this may be related to a similar error, where transactions require a gasLimit. If I try to run certain transactions upon deploying, the first time (only) I receive:

`Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

Adding a `{ gasLimit }` does indeed fix that problem.

Comment: How do you call testView() function? (Can you post your code?)
Did you try calling the function from Etherscan's API?

Comment: you are sending a transaction to a view method. you need just to call it (it is only a read function and don't need tx). by the way, methods that don't change data and don't even read data from storage should be pure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [GitHub issue on ethersjs](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/1244) insists that my error was due to using the "wrong network," and indeed that was the problem. Specifically, I had misconfigured my deployment files such that Ropsten and Rinkeby were saved inverted, such that each was using the contract addresses from the other.